# Automatic redirect to SharePoint mobile App

Tags: sharepoint-online

we have the problem, that when the user is opening a SharePoint Online site on an iPhone he is redirected to the SharePoint mobile App. Any option to disable this behaviour?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chrome to open the SharePoint online site.

In my environment, i install the SharePoint online app, and i can open the SharePoint online site in the Chrome:
[image]

In the Chrome, you can set Request Desktop site, You will see the site in a similar picture

Answer (score 0):

Is this SharePoint site a Publishing Portal?  If so, it could be that the device channel is directing their traffic incorrectly for their device.

Here's a link from Microsoft describing device channels.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-device-channels

Here's also a Youtube video discussing device channels:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ul8YanNBAY

Hope this is helpful,

Matt